# How to get the group expression portion of a matching expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the var `expression = /(a.)|(b.)|(c.)/;`, to match the `var value = "axx"`, I would like to be able to get the portion of `expression` that matched the `value`, in this case, `(a.)`

(This is a repost of a now-deleted post, which was erroneously, but understandably marked as duplicate. what I am trying to obtain is the portion of the regular expression, not the portion of the matching string).

Comment: Hmm why not trying to match with three different expressions instead?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, you only need to check which capturing group is filled.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat i want to use a much longer expression, so i would like to avoid as many loops as possible

Comment: Yes, check `if (m[1]) {....}`

Comment: Yeah, how about this `[/(a.)/,/(b.)/,/(c.)/].filter((x) => str.match(x))`

Comment: @X.Jacobs Your attitude is going to make people less likely to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFirstMatchedGroupIndex(regex, test_str) {
   var result = test_str.match(regex);
   if (result) {
       return result.splice(1).findIndex(x => x);
   }
}

var reg = /(a.)|(b.)|(c.)/;

getFirstMatchedGroupIndex(reg, "axx"); // 0
getFirstMatchedGroupIndex(reg, "bxx"); // 1
getFirstMatchedGroupIndex(reg, "cxx"); // 2
getFirstMatchedGroupIndex(reg, "xxx"); // undefined
```

This function takes advantage of the fact that in case of a match the string method `match` returns an array containing the following entries:

- as first index: the portion of the test string, which matched the regular expression.
- the following indices contain the contents of the captured groups (counted from left two right in the given regular expression), when a group didn't match, undefined is saved instead.

Comment: sorry, but where are you running that code? not sure what you mean with `x => x`, dude, is that even javascript

Comment: yes, it's JavaScript, I'm using the new ES6 arrow functions, the fragment in question could be written more explicity findIndex(function(item) { return item }); If you are using an older browser or want to be backwards compatible, use this code.

Comment: oh, this might look weird to have a function just returning it's parameter. It's called an identity function. Here it's needed, because findIndex, returns the index of the first item that does return a truthy value when passed to the given function (here: the identity).

Comment: oh boy, the magical variable `x` must do some pretty amazing stuff for you, because i don't see how you could otherwise be getting any results

Comment: here is a very, very verbose sample that might clarify some things for your: [undefined, undefined, "something", undefined].findIndex(function(item) { if (item != undefined) { return true } else { return false }});